# Struggling to find syntax error in my screeps code for repairing roads (unexpected token else)

Tags: javascript, screeps

Below is my script for my builder creeps. The creeps are able to build just fine, but my script throws an error on the repair section I wrote. The entire building script is pasted below:

```
var roleBuilder = {

    /** @param {Creep} creep **/
    run: function(creep) {

        if(creep.memory.building && creep.carry.energy == 0) {
            creep.memory.building = false;
            creep.say(' harvest');
        }
        if(!creep.memory.building && creep.carry.energy == creep.carryCapacity) {
            creep.memory.building = true;
            creep.say(' build');
        }

        if(creep.memory.building) {
            var targets = creep.room.find(FIND_CONSTRUCTION_SITES);
            if(targets.length) {
                if(creep.build(targets[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                    creep.moveTo(targets[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffffff'}});
                }
            }
            else {
                targets = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {
                    filter: (structure) => {
                        return (structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_ROAD && structure.hits < (structure.hitsMax * 0.25));
                        if(targets.length) {
                            if(creep.build(targets[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                                creep.moveTo(targets[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffffff'}});

                            }

                        }

                    }

                });
                else {
                    var sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES);
                    if(creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                        creep.moveTo(sources[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
                    }
                }
            }    
        };
    }
}

module.exports = roleBuilder;
```

I have tried online tools such as JSLint to attempt to solve my syntax error, but this has been unsuccessful. I am almost certain the error is in this section as removing the building code fixes the error.

The error thrown is below:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
    at Object.h:5:31901
    at main:3:19
    at eval:71:4
    at Object.h:5:31901
    at Object.c.runCode:6:16531

I would appreciate any help you can offer, as I am relatively new to Javascript.

EDIT: The problem is now solved. For anyone who finds this useful, here is my fixed code:

```
var roleBuilder = {

    /** @param {Creep} creep **/
    run: function(creep) {

        if(creep.memory.building && creep.carry.energy == 0) {
            creep.memory.building = false;
            creep.say(' harvest');
        }
        if(!creep.memory.building && creep.carry.energy == creep.carryCapacity) {
            creep.memory.building = true;
            creep.say(' build');
        }
        if(creep.memory.building) {
            var targets = creep.room.find(FIND_CONSTRUCTION_SITES);
            if(targets.length) {
                if(creep.build(targets[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                    creep.moveTo(targets[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffffff'}});
                }
            }
            else {
                targets = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {
                    filter: (structure) => {
                        return (structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_ROAD && structure.hits < (structure.hitsMax * 0.25));
                        if(targets.length) {
                            if(creep.build(targets[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                                creep.moveTo(targets[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffffff'}});
                            }
                    }
                        }         
                        });
                   }
                }
                else {
                    var sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES);
                    if(creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                        creep.moveTo(sources[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}}); 
            }    
        };
    }
}

module.exports = roleBuilder;
```

Comment: you have an else after targets which does not have an if before

Comment: The last `else` has no `if`.

Comment: The variable targets is used several times, where exactly in the code do you mean? I've tried shifting the else statements around but can't find where it should go. The intended behavior is that if the creep memory is building, the builder creeps should search for construction sites. If none are found, the creeps should attempt to repair any road with hits lower than 25% of maximum. Finally, if there are no badly damaged roads or construction sites, the builder should return to harvesting. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Either you use `if ... else` or you use `if ... else if ... else`. Further more, I think you are missing a `}` before that last `else` (but it still wouldn't be valid with it). Currently you are using 2 else branches, what should the second branch base on to be selected? It doesn't make any sense

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to solve the problem, and the fixed code has been copied into my original post.

Comment: This is not how Stack Exchange works. This is an answer--you put your answer here and leave it out of your question. Do not edit your question to put the answer in it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not let the fact that the community are sticklers for etiquette get you down. Just remove your solution from the question and place it in this answer. (You did better than many new users: code sample, exact error message. Keep it up.)